# Is it possible to prompt user for input in any grunt task?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I'm attempting to use Grunt to make a directory in a project for new posts to a blog.  It would essentially create a directory inside of a `posts` directory that is named `YYYYMMDDDD-PostNameInPascalCase`.

In order to do this, I'd have to prompt the user for post name each time that I execute the task.  I know that grunt-init prompts users for creating projects from project templates, but I'm curious if there's a way to do this inside the `Gruntfile.js` file for an already established project.

Any thoughts?

Comment: you mean on any any? like asking you for input before running something like grunt-contrib-compass?

Comment: @coma Yup - exactly. I have a feeling I'm wishing here. Even if it required modifying a specific task though, that'd be okay too.

Comment: Latest docs, with alternatives to create "dynamic tasks" https://gruntjs.com/frequently-asked-questions#dynamic-alias-tasks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's been a while since this question was last asked, but there is a project on Github that attempts to do what the questioner was looking for. It's called `grunt-prompt` and here's the url: https://github.com/dylang/grunt-prompt. It's basically a way to integrate prompts into the Gruntfile. From the project readme you would do something like:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  prompt: {
    target: {
      options: {
        questions: [
        {
          config: 'config.name', // arbitray name or config for any other grunt task
           type: '<question type>', // list, checkbox, confirm, input, password
          message: 'Question to ask the user',
          default: 'value', // default value if nothing is entered
          choices: 'Array|function(answers)',
          validate: function(value), // return true if valid, error message if invalid
          filter:  function(value), // modify the answer
          when: function(answers) // only ask this question when this function returns true
        }
      ]
    }
  },
},
})
```

Comment: You should update your answer to include the new [then](http://jsfiddle.net/xoLbweys) method:https://github.com/dylang/grunt-prompt#release-history

Comment: I use Gulp now instead of Grunt, so if this answer is outdated, feel free to update it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do something like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('makePost', 'Make a new post dir.', function(n) {
  if (n == null) {
    grunt.log.warn('Post name must be specified, like makePost:PostNameGoesHere.');
  }

  // Run other tasks here
  grunt.task.run('foo:' + n, 'bar:' + n, 'baz:' + n);
});
```

For more infomation and source on how to pass some arguments look at the [Grunt FAQ](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-can-i-share-parameters-across-multiple-tasks).